# Cannot convert value of type '(Result<Model>) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Result<_>) -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting this error and have no idea how to solve it. Even attempting to clarify the generic type doesn't seem to work. Any solution would be helpful as the Swift compiler really isn't giving me much to go on.

Here's my function:

```
public func request<T: JSONEncodable, K: JSONDecodable>(_ url: URLConvertible, httpMethod: HTTPMethod, query: [URLQueryItem]? = nil, body: T? = nil, completion: @escaping (Result<K>) -> Void) {
    do {
        var urlRequest = try buildURLRequest(httpMethod: httpMethod, url: url, withBase: baseURL, query: query, body: body)

        for middleware in requestMiddleware {
            try middleware.run(request: &urlRequest)
        }

        session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, urlResponse, error) in
            do {
                var data = data
                var urlResponse = urlResponse
                var error = error

                for middleware in self.responseMiddleware {
                    try middleware.run(data: &data, urlResponse: &urlResponse, error: &error)
                }

                if let error = error {
                    throw error
                } else if let data = data {
                    completion(.success(urlResponse as! HTTPURLResponse, try self.jsonDecoder.decode(K.self, from: data)))
                } else {
                    completion(.failure(HTTPClientError.nilResponseData))
                }
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }).resume()
    } catch {
        completion(.failure(error))
    }
}
```

Result enum:

```
internal enum Result<T: JSONDecodable> {

    case success(HTTPURLResponse, T)
    case failure(Error)

}
```

And how I'm calling it:

```
httpClient.request("hi", httpMethod: .get, completion: { (result: Result<Model>) -> Void in
    switch result {
        case .success(httpURLResponse, value):
            print("nice")
        case .failure(error):
            print("nice")
    }
})
```

Comment: why don't you use `Codable` instead of `T: JSONEncodable, K: JSONDecodable`

Answer (score 0):

Error is because of `body: T? = nil`. Compiler is unable to resolve generic `T`. You must provide the body that confirms protocol `JSONEncodable`.

For Example

```
struct ExampleBody: JSONEncodable {

}
```

And now

```
let body: ExampleBody = Body()
httpClient.request("hi", httpMethod: .get, body:body, completion: { (result: Result<Model>) -> Void in
    switch result {
        case .success(httpURLResponse, value):
            print("nice")
        case .failure(error):
            print("nice")
    }
})
```

---

OR as you are just passing body to `buildURLRequest` you don't need `T`

```
public func request<K: JSONDecodable>(_ url: URLConvertible, httpMethod: HTTPMethod, query: [URLQueryItem]? = nil, body: JSONEncodable? = nil, completion: @escaping (Result<K>) -> Void) {
    //....
}
```